# How to navigate to Salesforce Account record on clicking the Google Map marker

Tags: google-map

I am displaying all account record close to my current location on Google Maps. I need to navigate a user to the particular account record in Salesforce once he chooses a marker on the map and clicks on it. Any ideas how to achieve this?
Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SF.SE Roger. Have you looked at any of the Docs related to the use of mobile cards in SF1? Obviously, you'll need to build on the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) that's used in the examples provided in the [Force.com Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) and in the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/).

I would recommend taking the target location and passing it to the user's mobile device's Navigation App rather than creating your own navigation page results taken from the User's location. Otherwise, you'll need to call up Google Map directions from a Flex Page by sending the User's location along with the destination the User has selected, and use the Google API to return directions to the destination based on the User's GPS current location. You'll need to create a mobile app of some kind to do that.

BTW, to help with what you want to accomplish, there's a free app on the app exchange called [Address Geolocator 1.0](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5V0LEAV) which allows locating the address of selected entity records on a Google map.